# clip a plot to sub-parts then merge

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a start photo (StartShot) with 0-400, 0-400 coordinates:

[image]

And this path:

```
In[27]:= newpaths = Accumulate[Join[startingpoints, dxy]]
Out[27]= {{377.025, 272.122}, {373.537, 322.001}, {326.261, 
  305.722}, {319.303, 256.209}, {362.161, 230.457}, {411.788, 
  236.55}, {417.015, 286.276}, {392.015, 329.578}, {385.056, 
  379.091}, {374.661, 330.184}, {422.957, 343.125}, {375.681, 
  359.403}, {395.218, 405.428}, {443.033, 420.047}, {418.792, 
  463.778}, {467.307, 451.682}, {420.948, 432.951}, {470.332, 
  440.773}, {430.932, 409.99}, {390.481, 380.601}, {433.782, 355.601}}
```

[image]

Then I would like to clip it into 400 x 400 sub-parts, from the origo (0,0):

```
worldsize=400;
lineplot1 = 
  ListLinePlot[newpaths, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, 
   Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, worldsize}, {0, worldsize}}];
lineplot2 = 
  ListLinePlot[newpaths, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, 
   Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotRange -> {{ worldsize, 2 worldsize}, { 0, worldsize}}];
lineplot3 = 
 ListLinePlot[newpaths, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, 
  Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> {{ worldsize, 2 worldsize}, { worldsize, 2 worldsize}}]
lineplot4 = 
  ListLinePlot[newpaths, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, 
   Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, worldsize}, { worldsize, 2 worldsize}}];
```

Then I merge them:

```
fullworld = 
 ImageCompose[StartShot, {lineplot1, lineplot2, lineplot3, lineplot4}]
```

[image]

**Is any way to simplify this kind of task? Cutting the plot into sub-parts, and merge them?** For example automate the creation of lineplots.

Comment: Probably you [edit] your question to clarify what are the specifications of the end result you need. Is it related to `ImagePartition` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ImageCompose[StartShot, ListLinePlot[newpaths, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> #] & /@ 
    Flatten[Table[{{i - 1, i}, {j - 1, j}}, {i, 2}, {j, 2}] worldsize, 1]]
```

gives the desired image.

[image]

**Addendum**

If, as suggested by the OP in a comment below, the random walk proceeds beyond `2 worldsize` in either dimension, the `ListLinePlot` must be broken into more segments, which can be done as follows.

```
Ceiling[Max[#]/worldsize] & /@ Transpose[newpaths];
ImageCompose[StartShot, ListLinePlot[newpaths, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, 
    PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> #] & /@ 
    Flatten[Table[{{i - 1, i}, {j - 1, j} }, {i, First@%}, {j, Last@%}] worldsize, 1]]
```

For instance, if `{833.782, 155.601}, {133.782, 955.601}` is appended to the end of `newpaths`, the figure becomes

[image]

Note that the coordinates of each point in `newpaths` are assumed not to become negative.  If one or both do, the lower bounds on `i` and `j`, now equal to `1`, also must be modified.  An expression of the sort

```
Floor[Min[#]/worldsize] & /@ Transpose[newpaths];
```

would suffice.

Comment: That's what I needed I will accept it. I only miss a little modification for define 'i' and 'j' from the path coordinates and the world size (400).
For example the random walk can get a coordinate (940,100), then I must pick two plot from the right side. Many thanks!

Comment: @pnz1337  I do not understand what is meant by "pick two plot from the right side".  Please explain.

Comment: So the plot is a periodic (like a torus world in 2d), thus a random walk can wander too far from the starting point. Its origin is in the starting domain: bottom-left coordinate (0,0), top-right coordinate (400,400). But the walk can go out from the boundaries, for example to a coordinate (940,100), and then I need all of those (400x400) size windows, which the move crossed. So the second window from the right must be clip for sure. So the 'paths' has to be analysed to define the clipper windows.

Comment: Many thanks again !